# Is a switch on an enum inside a loop good style

Tags: java, coding-style, enums, switch-statement

I have a problem related with implementing something in Java and I guess Enums are a part of it (or maybe it's just me who made them a part of the problem.

So the thing is I have a model class, lets say it has 3 fields:

```
class ConferenceInfo {
    String name;
    Date date;
    String location;

    public boolean compareByName(ConferenceInfo other) {
        return getName().equals(other.getName());
    }

    public boolean compareByDate(ConferenceInfo other) {
        return getDate().compareTo(other.getDate()) == 0;
    }

    public boolean compareByLocation(ConferenceInfo other) {
        return getLocation().equals(other.getLocation());
    }
}
```

I have a list of pairs of those objects that I have to compare:

```
List<Pair<ConferenceInfo, ConferenceInfo>>
```

Now, this would be pretty easy, if I could just override an equals method, but in this case it's a little bit different - I have to compare those objects by values of their fields and output the number of them that differ. In order to do so I've created an enum:

```
public enum FieldType {
    NAME,
    DATE,
    LOCATION
}
```

and created a method (in my Measurement class, that has aformentioned list of pairs) that takes FieldType as a parameter and does something like this:

```
for (Pair<ConferenceInfo, ConferenceInfo> result : results) {
    ConferenceInfo first = result.getFirst();
    ConferenceInfo second = result.getSecond();

    switch (field) {
    case NAME:
        if (!first.compareByName(second)) {
            differentValues++;
        }
        break;
    case DATE:
        if (!first.compareByDate(second)) {
            differentValues++;
        }
        break;
    case LOCATION:
        if (!first.compareByLocation(second)) {
            differentValues++;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

It works, but I'm wondering if the way I coded it is a good practice or should I write it differently.. I kind of don't like switching inside a loop, but maybe it's just me :)

Comment: So do you call your method three times (once with each `FieldType`) and add the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use polymorphism instead of your switch:

```
public enum FieldType {
    NAME {
        @Override
        public boolean areEqual(ConferenceInfo c1, ConferenceInfo c2) {
            return c1.compareByName(c2);
        }
    },
    DATE {
        @Override
        public boolean areEqual(ConferenceInfo c1, ConferenceInfo c2) {
            return c1.compareByDate(c2);
        }
    },
    LOCATION {
        @Override
        public boolean areEqual(ConferenceInfo c1, ConferenceInfo c2) {
            return c1.compareByLocation(c2);
        }
    };

    public abstract boolean areEqual(ConferenceInfo c1, ConferenceInfo c2);
}
```

And then, in your code:

```
for (Pair<ConferenceInfo, ConferenceInfo> result : results) {
    ConferenceInfo first = result.getFirst();
    ConferenceInfo second = result.getSecond();
    if (!field.areEqual(first, second)) {
        differentValues++;
    }
}
```

This has the additional advantage that, if a new enum value appears, you won't have a risk of forgetting to add a case to the switch.

Comment: I was thinking about that for a while, but I was worried that coupling an enum with my model class might be a bad practice (I really put a lot of effort into writing a clean code, so I might be wrong). However, this looks clean enough for me and I thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if I put the logic code of comparing the fields into the enum as well? I mean instead of "return c1.compareByName(c2);" wouldn't it be better to put just "return c1.getName().equals(c2.getName());" ?

Comment: It seems to me that the enum doesn't represent information here, and is used specifically for this business logic. So coupling it with the model isn't a problem. And yes, if the compareBy methods in the model are only used in the enum, you could put it in the enum directly.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if i miss something, but in this case I would implement a method in the simplemodel class and to check the different values:

```
class SimpleModel  {
     ...

    int differentFields(SimpleModel obj){
        int differentValues = 0;
        if (!this.compareByName(obj)) {
            differentValues++;
        }
        if (!first.compareByDate(second)) {
             differentValues++;
        }
        if (!first.compareByLocation(second)) {
            differentValues++;
        }
        return differentValues;
    }
}
```

and in the method that compares the pairs, use it

```
for (Pair<ConferenceInfo, ConferenceInfo> result : results) {
    ConferenceInfo first = result.getFirst();
    ConferenceInfo second = result.getSecond();
    first.differentFields(second);
}
```

Comment: That would not be a valid `compareTo(...)` method and would break the Comparable contract since it *always* returns a positive number regardless of whether one object should sort before or after another object. In other words, its comparison results are non-commutative for sign, and this is not allowed.